# Can I use a 32-bit install DVD to repair a 64-bit install and vice versa?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, installation

Got a few questions for all of ya:

1) Can I use a 32 bit Windows 7/Vista DVD to repair a 64 bit Windows 7/Vista install and vice versa?

2) Can I use a 7 install DVD to repair a Vista install and vice versa?

Say I need to do a "Startup Repair", would it be possible if say, I have a corrupted Windows Vista 32-bit install, to use a Windows 7 64-bit install DVD to repair it?

What if I have a corrupted Windows 7 64-bit install?  Would I hurt anything if I tried it with a Windows Vista 32-bit DVD?

Just trying to figure this out in case I ever run into a situation where I don't have the appropriate DVD handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No. That said I believe there are Vista/7 DVD's that contain both 32bit and 64bit version of the OS so in that case you're probably good to go.

2) Possibly, The Windows 7 installer will detect an installation of Vista but you'd have to purposefully go into repair during install (which I believe is a link in the wizard on the second or third page in).

Though it's probably possible to use a Win 7 DVD to repair Vista it's unlikely to be possible vice versa (though it may be, I wouldn't be comfortable using an older OS DVD to repair the latest installation)